# CSS transition - invert the origin/direction

Tags: css

I'd like to make my label animation from top to bottom instead of from bottom to top. So the top is going to open and the bottom stay there:

```css
div.label4 {
  background-color: #4D6EF6;
  width: 278px;
  height: 388px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #4D6EF6;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  text-decoration: none;
  border: transparent;
  float: left;
  transition: width 1.5s, height 1.5s;
  transition-duration: 1.5s
}

div.label4:hover {
  height: 194px;
}
```

```html
<div class="label4"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap it in a parent with `flex-direction: column-reverse` and you're done:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  height: 388px;
  width: 278px;
}
```

```css
div.label4 {
  background-color: #4D6EF6;
  width: 278px;
  height: 388px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #4D6EF6;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  text-decoration: none;
  border: transparent;
  float: left;
  transition: width 1.5s, height 1.5s;
  transition-duration: 1.5s
}

div.label4:hover {
  height: 194px;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  height: 388px;
  width: 278px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="label4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution +1

Comment: Yours has `~2.5%` better support. A classic. :)

Comment: Ha, where can you get these figures?

Comment: You use `position`, which is CSS Level 1 and has 100% support. I used [`flexbox`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) - currently @ `97.71%`. Press [Show all] to see details. The coolest part about caniuse is it also gives you fixes for known issues. A real goldmine. Btw, [`CSS Grid`](http://caniuse.com/#search=grid) is coming. It was `~5%` a month ago.

Answer (score 2):

If you can alter the HTML you could create a container, and then position `.label4` using `position: absolute` and `bottom`

```css
.parent {
  height: 388px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

div.label4 {
  background-color: #4D6EF6;
  width: 278px;
  height: 388px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #4D6EF6;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  text-decoration: none;
  border: transparent;
  float: left;
  transition: width 1.5s, height 1.5s;
  transition-duration: 1.5s;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

div.label4:hover {
  height: 194px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="label4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your desire animation by `transform` which is more flexible and better and set `transform-origin` to each side your element,

```css
div.label4 {
  background-color: #4D6EF6;
  width: 278px;
  height: 388px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #4D6EF6;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  text-decoration: none;
  border: transparent;
  transition: transform 1.5s;
  transform: scaleY(1);
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}

div.label4:hover {
  transform: scaleY(0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="label4"></div>
```

Comment: This is indeed a better (less costly) animation technique but comes with a price: the element will no longer be able to hold any content (an image or a vertically centered title) as they will get distorted by the animation. (OP said it's a label animation - labels usually hold information of some kind).

Comment: Not just that, if element has border-radius, it will get distorted.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu It's true, but it depends on the propose of animation